# Touchpad not detected in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, debian, touchpad, kali-linux

Running a Dell 3147 11 inch 2 in 1 with Kali installed on the ssd, it doesn't detect the touchpad. I looked under xinput and it doesn't show up.

I've tried this: https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad too.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! Woot!

```
rmmod i2c_designware_platform
rmmod i2c_designware_core
```

add the following into a modprobe conf file.

```
blacklist i2c_designware_platform
blacklist i2c_designware_core
```

Fixed!

Comment: It would be nice (and a better answer) if you said how this solved your issue.

Comment: Incorrect drivers were being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by some changes during boot in grub. Do it as follows:

> 1. Run `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`
> 2. Locate the line
>
>    ```
>    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" // or may be only ="quiet"
>    ```
>
>    edit it so that it looks like the following
>
>    ```
>    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
>    ```
> 3. Save and run this command in terminal: `sudo update-grub`
> 4. Run the following commands in terminal:
>
>    ```
>     echo "blacklist i2c_hid" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/i2c-hid.conf
>     sudo depmod -a
>     sudo update-initramfs -u
>     echo "synaptics_i2c" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
>    ```
> 5. Reboot

---

Thanks to [pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6) from [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) for the correct solution:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/592925/dell-inspiron-3551-unresponsive-touchpad

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). I fixed your answer this time but please be aware how you should quote text copied from elsewhere.

Comment: i still don't get what is meant by quoting the text.I am new, so could you help me out (please). thanks in advance

Comment: http://superuser.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes

Comment: Thanks i got it by seeing your edited code posted by me.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to help (especially for non-DELL users) is to disable the ACPI option (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) by adding acpi=off to the kernel boot options.

Touchpad would work after that but since ACPI is used for hardware acceleration you will probably experience some higher CPU usage.